# JavaFX TableView selectionModel apparently out of sync with what's visible in the GUI

Tags: java, javafx, binding, predicate

We have a process that collects data and tries to automatically model it. We also have a reference for the data so we've got a process that compares the synthesized data against the reference, finding where it hits or misses, the misses being displayed prominently for user action.

To that end, I've created a JavaFX GUI in the "click on summary to display detail data" style where the synthesized data is selected from a `TableView` and the comparison and reference data are fetched from DB and displayed in auxiliary `TableView`s.

I'm also using some `CheckComboBox`  from ControlsFX as filters to manipulate what's visible in the synthesized data `TableView`.

So I have the typical `ObservableList<Data>` (the data itself) -> `FilteredList<Data>` (the list filtered by predicate-driven `CheckComboBox`es) -> `SortedList<Data>` (the list put into the `TableView`). So, to make it all work, I have to put a `ListChangeListener` on the `TableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` `ObservableList`.

So, to the point: On the occasion that (a) a filter is in selected state and (b) something is selected in the `TableView` and (c) the filter is changed, the predicate actions and the selectedItems listener kinda go nuts with some kind of mutually recursive back and forth until, at the end, the selectedItems listener thinks that all of the items in the list are selected whereas visually, only one or no things are actually selected. (This also leads to a flurry of DB requests because of all the back and forth changes, which is really the main annoyance.)

Here's some code that illustrates the problem:

```
package com.example.javafx;

import javafx.beans.property.*;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    public static enum Altruism {
        LAWFUL, NEUTRAL, CHAOTIC;
    }

    public static enum Goodness {
        GOOD, NEUTRAL, EVIL;
    }

    private int id;
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final ObjectProperty<Altruism> altruism = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private final ObjectProperty<Goodness> goodness = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(int id, String n, String e, Altruism a, Goodness g) {
        setId(id);
        setName(n);
        setEmail(e);
        setAltruism(a);
        setGoodness(g);
    }

    private void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public final Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public final void setName(String n) {
        name.set(n);
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public final void setEmail(String e) {
        email.set(e);
    }

    public final String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
        return email;
    }

    public final void setAltruism(Altruism a) {
        altruism.set(a);
    }

    public final Altruism getAltruism() {
        return altruism.get();
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<Altruism> altruismProperty() {
        return altruism;
    }

    public final void setGoodness(Goodness a) {
        goodness.set(a);
    }

    public final Goodness getGoodness() {
        return goodness.get();
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<Goodness> goodnessProperty() {
        return goodness;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return getName().compareTo(o.getName());
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        String value = super.toString();
        value += " " + name;
        return value;
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.javafx;

import static com.example.javafx.Person.Altruism.CHAOTIC;
import static com.example.javafx.Person.Goodness.GOOD;
import java.util.*;

public class Database {

    static final Person[] PEOPLE_TEST_DATA = {
        new Person(0, "Martha", "martha@gmail.com", CHAOTIC, GOOD),
        new Person(1, "Pat", "pat@gmail.com", CHAOTIC, Person.Goodness.NEUTRAL),
        new Person(2, "Marisa", "marisa@gmail.com", Person.Altruism.NEUTRAL, Person.Goodness.NEUTRAL),
        new Person(3, "Russel", "russel@gmail.com", Person.Altruism.CHAOTIC, Person.Goodness.NEUTRAL),
        new Person(4, "Ron", "ron@gmail.com", Person.Altruism.LAWFUL, Person.Goodness.NEUTRAL)
    };

    public final List<Person> fetchAll() {
        List<Person> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Person p : PEOPLE_TEST_DATA) {
            data.add(p);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public final List<Person> fetchByIds(List<Integer> ids) {
        List<Person> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Person p : PEOPLE_TEST_DATA) {
            if (ids.contains(p.getId())) {
                data.add(p);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.javafx;

import com.example.javafx.Person.Altruism;
import com.example.javafx.Person.Goodness;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.*;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.collections.transformation.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.control.CheckComboBox;

public class Main extends Application {

    CheckComboBox altruismSelector
            = new CheckComboBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Altruism.values()));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    Database db = new Database();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
        VBox controls = new VBox(5);

        Button clearFilter = new Button("reset filter");
        clearFilter.setOnAction(event -> {
            resetChecks();
        });

        controls.getChildren().setAll(
                new Label("altruism:"),
                altruismSelector,
                clearFilter);

        ObjectProperty<Predicate<Person>> altruismPredicate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        altruismPredicate.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
                () -> person -> {
                    final Altruism a = person.getAltruism();
                    final ObservableList<Altruism> checkedItems = altruismSelector.getCheckModel().getCheckedItems();
                    return checkedItems.contains(a) || checkedItems.isEmpty();
                }, altruismSelector.getCheckModel().getCheckedItems()));

        ObservableList<Person> people = FXCollections.observableArrayList(db.fetchAll());
        FilteredList<Person> filteredPeople = people.filtered(p -> true);
        SortedList<Person> sortedPeople = filteredPeople.sorted();

        filteredPeople.predicateProperty()
                .bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
                        () -> altruismPredicate.get()/*.and(goodnessPredicate.get())*/,
                        altruismPredicate /*, goodnessPredicate*/));

        TableView<Person> peopleTableView = setupAllPeopleTableView(sortedPeople);
        
        ObservableList<Person> selectedPeople = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        TableView<Person> detailTableView = setupDetailedPersonTableView(selectedPeople);

        sortedPeople.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Person> c) {
                System.out.println(c.getList().size() + " items in visible list: " + c.getList());
            }
        });

        peopleTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Person> c) {
                System.out.println(c.getList().size() + " items selected: " + c.getList());
                selectedPeople.clear();
                List<Integer> ids = c.getList().stream()
                        .map(e->e.getId())
                        .distinct()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                selectedPeople.setAll(db.fetchByIds(ids));
            }
        });

        SplitPane tableViews = new SplitPane(peopleTableView, detailTableView);
        tableViews.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        
        layout.setCenter(tableViews);
        layout.setLeft(controls);

        resetChecks();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private TableView<Person> setupAllPeopleTableView(ObservableList<Person> people) {
        
        TableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn("name");
        nameColumn.setId("name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().nameProperty());
        
        TableColumn<Person, Altruism> altruismColumn = new TableColumn("altruism");
        altruismColumn.setId("altruism");
        altruismColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().altruismProperty());
        
        TableView<Person> peopleTableView = new TableView<>();
        peopleTableView.getColumns().setAll(
                nameColumn,
                altruismColumn
        );
        peopleTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        peopleTableView.setItems(people);
        return peopleTableView;
    }

    private TableView<Person> setupDetailedPersonTableView(ObservableList<Person> people) {

        TableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn("name");
        nameColumn.setId("name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().nameProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, String> emailColumn = new TableColumn("email");
        emailColumn.setId("email");
        emailColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().emailProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, Altruism> altruismColumn = new TableColumn("altruism");
        altruismColumn.setId("altruism");
        altruismColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().altruismProperty());
        
        TableColumn<Person, Goodness> goodnessColumn = new TableColumn("goodness");
        goodnessColumn.setId("goodness");
        goodnessColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().goodnessProperty());

        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.getColumns().setAll(
                nameColumn,
                emailColumn,
                altruismColumn,
                goodnessColumn
        );
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        tableView.setItems(people);
        
        return tableView;
    }

    private void resetChecks() {
        System.out.println("resetChecks");
        altruismSelector.getCheckModel().clearChecks();
    }

    private static void delay(final int delay) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

If you run "Main", above, engage the filter of NEUTRAL, select Marisa, then click on the reset button, you'll see the weirdness in the logging as a well as the listener reporting everything selected when visually, only Marisa is selected.

I expect that there's a problem with the filter changing the underlying `SortedList` which is indirectly tied to the `TableView` `SelectionModel`, but I don't know where to go from here. Am I doing it wrong or is there perhaps a bug in JavaFX/ControlsFX that might be exacerbating this problem?

Edit: I completely forgot to mention that this is with Java 1.8/JavaFX 8 and ControlsFX 8.40.18.

Comment: I don't see the behavior you're describing. After pressing the reset button, the only weirdness I see is that the listeners seem to be being invoked with some intermediate state. The selected items switch between 0 and 1 selected; the visible items switch between 1 and 5. That's annoying, and arguably a bug in one or both libraries, but it's never really inconsistent. I never see everything reported as selected, and the state after the final listener notification is correct. JavaFX 18.0.1 and ControlsFX 11.1.2.

Comment: One thing I do see is that if you select multiple rows in the table, then change the filter, the multiple selection is not respected. (E.g. select Martha and Pat, then filter for "Chaotic", only the last selection remains.) But again the logs are consistent with the visual data.

Comment: I’ve found SortedList is unreliable.  I haven’t tried investigating the reason behind it.  I was able to achieve correct behavior (I think) by using `setupAllPeopleTableView(sortedPeople)` and by using the TableView’s own sorting.

Comment: Most probably SortedList is innocent :) My usual suspects are a) FilteredList - on change of the predicate its sends bulk replaced notification for its complete old/new content (inside its contract but could do better)  and b) selectedItems - its change notification is notoriously broken and probably has to take most of the blame.

Comment: @VGR so you simply used the filtered list as the data for the TableView directly? Intriguing.

Comment: @James_D I tried it with Java 18, Java FX 18.0.1, and ControlsFX 11.1.2, and the behavior changed. So, obviously, there's a bug that got fixed somewhere along the way. So thanks for affirming that I wasn't doing it COMPLETELY wrong. Now I just have to see about a workaround or other approach.

Comment: on the dark side: automatic sync'ing of selection state _cannot_ work as long as FilteredList doesn't send a fine-grained list change notification (see https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8092288): the selection model simply has no means to know what to keep (in current versions the special handling of selectedIndex at least is correct, as @James_D noted). The way out is manual sync'ing: grab the selection state before updating the predicate -> update the predicate -> reset the selection to the previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a workaround for the bug by not using the `SortedList<Data>` transform but instead handling the updates from the `FilteredList<Data>` and manipulating the final list in my own handler. This is similar to @kleopatra's suggestion in the comments.

```
package com.example.javafx;

import com.example.javafx.Person.Altruism;
import com.example.javafx.Person.Goodness;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.*;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.collections.transformation.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView.TableViewSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.control.CheckComboBox;

public class Solution extends Application {

    CheckComboBox altruismSelector
            = new CheckComboBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Altruism.values()));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    Database db = new Database();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
        VBox controls = new VBox(5);

        Button clearFilter = new Button("reset filter");
        clearFilter.setOnAction(event -> {
            resetChecks();
        });

        controls.getChildren().setAll(
                new Label("altruism:"),
                altruismSelector,
                clearFilter);

        ObjectProperty<Predicate<Person>> altruismPredicate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        altruismPredicate.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
                () -> person -> {
                    final Altruism a = person.getAltruism();
                    final ObservableList<Altruism> checkedItems = altruismSelector.getCheckModel().getCheckedItems();
                    return checkedItems.contains(a) || checkedItems.isEmpty();
                }, altruismSelector.getCheckModel().getCheckedItems()));

        ObservableList<Person> people = FXCollections.observableArrayList(db.fetchAll());
        FilteredList<Person> filteredPeople = people.filtered(p -> true);
        ObservableList<Person> sortedPeople = FXCollections.observableArrayList(filteredPeople);
        TableView<Person> peopleTableView = setupAllPeopleTableView(sortedPeople);
        
        filteredPeople.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Person>c) {
                TableViewSelectionModel selection = peopleTableView.getSelectionModel();
                // capture existing selection from the table's selection model
                List<Person> selectedPeople = new ArrayList<>(selection.getSelectedItems());
                // clear table's selection
                selection.clearSelection();
                // jam the contents of the change into the people list
                sortedPeople.setAll(c.getList());
                // restore selections if they're still in the list after the change
                for (Person p : selectedPeople) {
                    if (c.getList().contains(p)) {
                        selection.select(p);
                    }
                }
                // help out the GC?
                selectedPeople.clear();
            }
        });

        filteredPeople.predicateProperty()
                .bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
                        () -> altruismPredicate.get()/*.and(goodnessPredicate.get())*/,
                        altruismPredicate /*, goodnessPredicate*/));

        
        ObservableList<Person> selectedPeople = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        TableView<Person> detailTableView = setupDetailedPersonTableView(selectedPeople);

        sortedPeople.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Person> c) {
                System.out.println(c.getList().size() + " items in visible list: " + c.getList());
            }
        });

        peopleTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Person> c) {
                System.out.println(c.getList().size() + " items selected: " + c.getList());
                selectedPeople.clear();
                List<Integer> ids = c.getList().stream()
                        .map(e->e.getId())
                        .distinct()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                selectedPeople.setAll(db.fetchByIds(ids));
            }
        });

        SplitPane tableViews = new SplitPane(peopleTableView, detailTableView);
        tableViews.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        
        layout.setCenter(tableViews);
        layout.setLeft(controls);

        resetChecks();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private TableView<Person> setupAllPeopleTableView(ObservableList<Person> people) {
        
        TableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn("name");
        nameColumn.setId("name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().nameProperty());
        
        TableColumn<Person, Altruism> altruismColumn = new TableColumn("altruism");
        altruismColumn.setId("altruism");
        altruismColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().altruismProperty());
        
        TableView<Person> peopleTableView = new TableView<>();
        peopleTableView.getColumns().setAll(
                nameColumn,
                altruismColumn
        );
        peopleTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        peopleTableView.setItems(people);
        return peopleTableView;
    }

    private TableView<Person> setupDetailedPersonTableView(ObservableList<Person> people) {

        TableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn("name");
        nameColumn.setId("name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().nameProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, String> emailColumn = new TableColumn("email");
        emailColumn.setId("email");
        emailColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().emailProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, Altruism> altruismColumn = new TableColumn("altruism");
        altruismColumn.setId("altruism");
        altruismColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().altruismProperty());
        
        TableColumn<Person, Goodness> goodnessColumn = new TableColumn("goodness");
        goodnessColumn.setId("goodness");
        goodnessColumn.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().goodnessProperty());

        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.getColumns().setAll(
                nameColumn,
                emailColumn,
                altruismColumn,
                goodnessColumn
        );
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        tableView.setItems(people);
        
        return tableView;
    }

    private void resetChecks() {
        System.out.println("resetChecks");
        altruismSelector.getCheckModel().clearChecks();
    }

    private static void delay(final int delay) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

It's not perfect, a bit brute-force, but it gets the job done for me. Remember, this is for Java 8/JavaFX 8 and ControlsFX 8.40.18. Newer setups may or may not need this workaround.